# How to apply a CSS property for a component from Typescript in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, datatable

I have an angular 4 application which displays an angular data table. I am using the [rowColors] property of the table to apply a color for the last row in the table by returning `rgb(112, 113, 205)`. I need to apply this color from a css property in my Typescript file.

Comment: Some code of what you're trying to do would be most helpful. It's not clear to me exactly what you're wanting to do.

Comment: angular `ViewChild()` is probably what you're after. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild